# Meteor isn't installing after removal of some files

Tags: meteor

I installed Meteor for Windows 7. On my computer, I have two partitions of my hard drive: C: for operating system, and D: for everything else. The C: drive has just enough space for the OS, so I wanted to install Meteor on D:. However, the installer directly installed onto C, and the installation stopped halfway through saying that it ran out of space.

I deleted some files to restart the installation (bad idea on my part). Specifically, I removed from the AppData\Local.meteor directory, the meteorsession file, prefetch files, and the PackageCache directory. I also deleted the PATH environment variable set up by the installation (only the AppData\Local.meteor directory; the other paths I didn't delete).

So I restarted my computer and started to install again and this time it doesn't download anything and just jumps directly to the "Meteor has now been installed" screen. I'm guessing that there's some leftover files hiding around somewhere that the installer uses to check to see if Meteor has already been installed. So what should I do to clear these/what's the actual cause of the issue?

Thanks!

Comment: Try `meteor --version`, to check if meteor is really installed. If that works, create a default app as `meteor create myApp` and see if the app is working fine.

Comment: I added the AppData\Local to the PATH variable and the terminal says that meteor is not a recognized command. The .meteor folder within the AppData\Local directory isn't even showing up after I run the installer.